# Retrieve all rows from the last possible 3 years (Laravel + Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, filter, eloquent

I'm trying to get all the rows I can in a Model, however it must be the last 3 possible years, as if I  have a result in the year 2020 but nothing in the year 2019 then it must search in 2018, 2017, but if I had a result in 2019 then it must search only for the results in 2018.

I've already gotten the hang of whereBetween, however I don't get any results from the database using the following query:

```
$year = $request->all();
$fromDate = $year['yearFrom'];
$toDate = $year['yearTo'];

return Tipico::whereBetween(
    DB::raw('date(created_at)'), [$fromDate, $toDate]
)
    ->get();
```

As you can see, I get the year from a post method which gives me the initial and finish year, however it doesn't validate the information I'm searching for, whats the best way to do it?

Comment: Whats the content of `$fromDate` and `$toDate`?

Comment: Two strings with the year sent via post. ```$fromDate=2012``` and ```$toDate=2020```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Carbon to create your dates:

```
$fromDate = Carbon::createFromDate($year['yearFrom'], 1, 1)->startOfDay();
$toDate = Carbon::createFromDate($year['yearTo'], 12, 31)->endOfDay();
```

Then in your query, `created_at` is already a datetime, so:

```
return Tipico::whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate, $toDate])->get();
```

Remember to include Carbon in your Class at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
```

or only

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

To get the data from the past 3 years, one option would be to run a query to see what years have the data you need.

So, let's use the `yearTo` as reference to his and select the top 3 years with data:

```
$years = Tipico::select(\DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as years'))
               ->where('created_at', '<=', $toDate)
               ->distinct()
               ->orderByRaw('YEAR(created_at) DESC')
               ->limit(3)
               ->get();
```

Now in `$years` you will have the 3 years. Now you can run the query with this years as parameter:

```
return Tipico::whereIn(\DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), $years)->get();
```

*Not sure if you can pass `$years` directly or need to transform to array. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly to get the results from the initial year to the last year, however how can I get the last 3 years where there are results in order to get the initial year from the database and not from the user?

Comment: Edited, take a look @EmilianoPérez